# How to create my own arrow effects in illustrator CS 2

Tags: adobe-illustrator

In illustrator CS 2 you can use effects to add an arrow end to a line, which moves with the line if it is dragged or scaled, very useful :-) Is it possible to create my own arrow effects? For example I'd like to draw a small vertical line at the end and the beginning of my "original" line... something like this: |-------|. The two | | at each end should me moved automatically, whenever I scale the line.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You really can't edit or add arrowheads with Illustrator CS2. The arrows are hard coded into the app with absolutely no user-accessible way to add or edit them. Newer versions, especially CS5, have ample arrowhead editing abilities.

With CS2, your best bet is to create a pattern brush with the end caps you want.

[image: Create pattern brush in Illustrator CS2]

Note: In Illustrator CS6 or newer Adobe ships a "bar cap" arrowhead in the Stroke Panel (Arrow 27) and there may be no need for a custom brush in newer Illustrator versions.

Comment: Very cool! Today, you earn some points from me ;-)