# lines capped by lines in Adobe Illustrator

Tags: adobe-illustrator

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to create my own arrow effects in illustrator CS 2](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/5348/how-to-create-my-own-arrow-effects-in-illustrator-cs-2)

Is there an easy way of creating thin perpendicular lines capping the end of a line segment in Adobe Illustrator CS4? The sort of effect I'm looking for is this:

|------------------------|

(but without the dotted effect!). This is useful for example for adding dimensions on technical type drawings.

I would have expected I could do this easily either with add arrowheads or with line cap type options, but I can't find a way in Adobe Illustrator CS4. Obviously I'd prefer not to draw three separate line segments every time. I am struggling to investigate this as I'm not even sure what the proper term is for this type of line decoration.

Thanks for any suggestions.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can make your own custom "end caps" with a pattern brush.

To do so, start by drawing each segment. In your case, we need a "line" segment and an "end cap" segment:

[image: Pattern Brush Segments]

Now we need to create a swatch for each of these. Do so by selecting one of them and using `Edit → Define Pattern`. Alternatively, you could select one and drag it to the `Swatches` pane. Give each of them appropriate names to avoid confusion, something like "End Cap" and "Line Segment". You should end up with two new swatches in the `Swatches` pane:

[image: Swatches Pane]

Now we can create our pattern brush. Create a new brush from the `Brush Definition` Dropdown:

[image: Brush Definition]

Choose **`Pattern Brush`** from the New Brush box that pops up.

For the `Side Tile`, choose your Line Segment swatch. For the `Start Tile` and `End Tile`, chose your End Cap swatch. You can ignore the corner tiles. You can also set the Colorization Method to "Tints":

[image: Pattern Brush Settings]

Now, when you apply that brush to a line segment, it will have your custom end caps. Since we set the Colorization Method to "Tints", you can change the color of the stroke pattern easily.

[image: Measuring Sticks]